# Can someone explain how probabilistic counting works?

Tags: bigdata

Specifically around log log counting approach.

Answer (score 8):

I'll try and clarify the use of probabilistic counters although note that I'm no expert on this matter.

The aim is to count to very very large numbers using only a little space to store the counter (e.g. using a 32 bits integer).

Morris came up with the idea to maintain a "log count", so instead of counting *n*, the counter holds *log₂(n)*. In other words, given a value *c* of the counter, the real count represented by the counter is *2ᶜ*.

As logs are not generally of integer value, the problem becomes when the *c* counter should be incremented, as we can only do so in steps of 1.

The idea here is to use a "probabilistic counter", so for each call to a method `Increment` on our counter, we update the actual counter value with a probability *p*. This is useful as it can be shown that the *expected* value represented by the counter value *c* with probabilistic updates is in fact *n*. In other words, on *average* the value represented by our counter after *n* calls to `Increment` is in fact *n* (but at any one point in time our counter is probably has an error)! We are trading accuracy for the ability to count up to very large numbers with little storage space (e.g. a single register).

One scheme to achieve this, as described by Morris, is to have a counter value *c* represent the actual count 2ᶜ (i.e. the counter holds the log₂ of the actual count). We update this counter with probability 1/2ᶜ where *c* is the current value of the counter.

Note that choosing this "base" of 2 means that our actual counts are always multiples of 2 (hence the term "order of magnitude estimate"). It is also possible to choose other *b > 1* (typically such that *b < 2*) so that the error is smaller at the cost of being able to count smaller maximum numbers.

The log log comes into play because in base-2 a number *x* needs log₂ bits to be represented.

There are in fact many other schemes to approximate counting, and if you are in need of such a scheme you should probably research which one makes sense for your application.

References:

See [Philippe Flajolet](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/Flajolet85c.pdf) for a proof on the average value represented by the counter, or a much simpler treatment in the solutions to a problem 5-1 in the book "Introduction to Algorithms". The paper by Morris is usually behind paywalls, I could not find a free version to post here.

Comment: I found a free version of Morris's paper: https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/exc/reading/morris.pdf

Answer (score 0):

its not exactly for the log counting approach but i think it can help you,
using Morris' algorithm, the counter represents an "order of magnitude estimate" of the actual count.The approximation is mathematically unbiased.
To increment  the counter, a pseudo-random event is used, such that the incrementing is a probabilistic event. To save space, only the exponent is kept. For example, in base 2, the counter can estimate the count to be 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, and all of the powers of two. The memory requirement is simply to hold the exponent.
As an example, to increment from 4 to 8, a pseudo-random number would be generated such that a probability of .25 generates a positive change in the counter. Otherwise, the counter remains at 4. from wiki